# why does Paralle.for loose so badly

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

i am trying to benchmark For and Parallel For for copying a list into an individual list

here Points are struct of int x , int y

Below is the benchmark code :

```
var points = addPoints();
int nbPoints = points.Count;


Measure("Normal Forloop", () =>
{
    List<int> x = new List<int>(nbPoints);
    List<int> y = new List<int>(nbPoints);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbPoints; i++)
    {
        x.Add(points[i].X);
        y.Add(points[i].Y);
    }
});

Measure("Parallel Forloop", () =>
{
    ConcurrentBag<int> x = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    ConcurrentBag<int> y = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
    Parallel.For(0, nbPoints, i =>
    {
        x.Add(points[i].X);
        y.Add(points[i].Y);
    });
});
```

Now for a list size of NumberOfPoints = 1000000;

performance of normal for loop : 24 ms

performance of Parallel For loop : 367 ms

why did the parallel for loose so badly , is it because of concurrentbags ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall what is my mistake , sample size is same for both

Comment: To get the best parallel performance, threads should not share resources, even if those resources are thread-safe (like `ConcurrentBag`). You'll get better perf if each thread adds to its own private `List<>` and then you merge the lists at the very end - but that would defeat the point of this benchmark.

Comment: You have measured List vs ConcurrentBag much more than for vs ForEach

Comment: @dai , that is true but how do you explain a such a vast difference of performance

Comment: @KeshavRaghav Because `List<T>` and `ConcurrentBag<T>` work on entirely different principles.

Comment: @HenkHolterman what other choice do i have when using paralle.for each i cannot use list inside a parallel for

Comment: @KeshavRaghav Threads should not mutate (i.e. modify, write-to, etc) shared resources because when threads share resources it means they're reading and writing to the same memory locations, which means the CPU's cache system has to work inefficiently (remember each CPU core is its own full CPU) to ensure each core's state is synchronised. When multiple threads don't read/write to the same memory then the CPU's caches don't need to worry about keeping everything in-sync.

Comment: @KeshavRaghav 'No choice'  doesn't make it a valid comparison.

Comment: @HenkHolterman so you suggest i cannot parallise the above operation

Comment: You are only adding anyway, why don't you use a pre-sized array. still this is not the best way to benchmark, you should be using a benchmarking library like Benchmark.net. There are just so many factors that can trip you up when trying to determine what horse is faster. Like debug and release mode, is the debugger attached, sample size, comparing apples to apples

Comment: @MichaelRandall , how can i use array inside parallel.for , is it thread safe? or do you suggest me not to use TPL for this operation , my list will be of size 50k points , so i want to parallise it

Comment: If it is a presized array, and you are only walking through the indexes and not accessing any particular element form multiple threads then it is thread safe

Comment: @MichaelRandall even then parallel lost  
   Normal Forloop  Average time: 26.000ms
Parallel Forloop        Average time: 72.000ms

Comment: Now try with 1000000 items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207245/discussion-between-keshav-raghav-and-michael-randall).